# C# code behind - Accessing file from URL that requires username and password

Tags: c#, image, memorystream

on the aspx code behind page we are looping through a list of img URL to be displayed on the page.  To keep it simple - we are building the HTML as a string:

```
"<img width='100' src='" + items[i].ImgUrl + "' />"
```

the url is something like: https://www.mysite.com/User%20Photos/Profile%20Pictures/ismith_MThumb.jpg

If you are to click on the above URL (which won't work btw) it will prompt for username and password before the image is displayed.

So the key is to pass the username and password credentials and then allow the link to source the image.

I thought I could use memorystream but then that would just return the entire image.  I think.

Any suggestions?
thanks

Comment: This really depends on how the site itself is set up, and if it actually allows you to do stuff like that.  Usually you need to establish a session (which is what logging in does) to retrieve data.  Unless the website you're pulling images down from is explicitly under your control (i.e. you have access to the code base) I don't really know what to tell you, short of grabbing the images and hosting them elsewhere (which may or may not be legal, depending on copyrights, etc.)  If the site has proper security checks, trying to pass a url to it and save to a memorystream will not work.

Answer (score 0):

i got it after reading some more posts here about Memorystream. 
I did the following to set the credentials:

```
 WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(items[i].ImgUrl);
 req.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(hostWebAdmin, hostWebPassword, hostWebDomain);
 WebResponse response = req.GetResponse();
 Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
```

and then i read the stream into a Memorystream.
and then I did this to set the MemoryStream into an array:

```
string imgUrl = "data:image/jpg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(memStream.ToArray(), 0, memStream.ToArray().Length);
```

and then finally:

```
"<img src=\"" + imgUrl + "\" class=\"property-image\"/>"
```

thanks to all that took the time to look and offer advice!